# Change Icon color of query context menu dynamically?

Tags: jquery, font-awesome, contextmenu

I use jquery context menu with font-awesome icons. I like to change the color of the icon depending on the status of the object relating to the menu. e.g.

```
"locked": 
{
    name: i18next.t('default:infopanel.contextmenu.locked'),
    icon: "fa-lock",
    disabled: function (key, opt)
    {
        return !canToggleLocked(getInfoPanelJobFromDiv(opt.$trigger))
    }
}
```

So I already toggle the disable/enable on the jobs status. Now I want to do the same with the icon color (or even take another icon with different css values). It should be green in some cases and red in other (but not depending on the same status which makes it disable/enable). So I need a callback function for the icon similar to the one I use for the disable feature.

Is there any option to achieve this?

Comment: Change the CSS class on the icon when it's disabled/enabled, and have that class set the `color`

Comment: Ok, my fault. The color is not connected to the disable/enable. So it must have its own callback to check which color it should have. I made an edit

Comment: That's fine, but the approach is the same. Add/remove the CSS class to change the icon colour whenever your system needs to

Comment: Mh yes that's the idea. the disable callback will be called every time the menu is opened. So I can add or remove the class for the icon there. Some times the solution is so easy you do not see it directly in front of your nose. thanks

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff i know it's an old question but you can also use `show` event to assign a class to the menu element : https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/XWdeQre?editors=0010 (it seems more clean than using `disabled` callback)

Comment: Thats pretty cool. thanks yaya